# Some methods can't be resolved - android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android. I have some activity `FragmentTabsActivity extends FragmentActivity`, and that implements some tabs using `tabhost` (I know it is deprecated, but it is just to better understand). When some tab is active, I want to display some list item as a content.

This list is defined with some class `TabFragment extends ListFragment`. Now, I have

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
....
}
....
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

The problem is that neither `findViewById`, nor `getSystemService` are recognized. Why is it so ?

Comment: I think you need ` mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);`

Comment: @codeMagic, you're wright ! why now `getSystemService` is not recognized ?

Comment: Try `getActivity().getSystemService()`

Comment: You're welcome. I will post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Converting comments to answer**

`findViewById` is a method of a `Activity` that is inflated so there are a couple ways you can do it here but the simplest would be to change

```
mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```

to

```
mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```

by calling the method on the currently inflated `view` from the `Activity`.

For `getSystemService()` you need to use a reference to the `Activity` that this `fragment` is attached to to use this method so change

```
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

to

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to inflate a view from layout first then find the progressbar in that view.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate the view for your fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutname,container,false)
        // find the progressbar in your inflated view.
        mProgressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
....
        return view;
}
```

2.Use getActivity().

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```